# Multiply vector elements by a scalar value using STL and templates

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I wrote a small scientific simulation where I wanted to manipulate vectors with the same kind of functionality that Python's NumPy vectors use. Namely, I wanted to be able to add vectors together, multiply by constants, etc. I have need for both vectors of type int and floating point, so I wanted to template the overloading. As an example (and for something to review), I overloaded scalar multiplication as:

```
template <class T, class Q>
vector <T> operator*(const Q c, const vector<T> &A) {
  vector <T> R(A.size());
  for(int i=0;i<A.size();++i) 
    R[i] = c*A[i];
  return R;
}
```

The STL algorithm way I hinted at looks like this:

```
template <class T, class Q>
vector <T> operator*(const Q c, const vector<T> &A) {

  vector <T> R(A.size());
  std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), R.begin(),
                 std::bind1st(std::multiplies<T>(),c));
  return R;
}
```

I would appreciate all criticism relevant to code, style, flow. My project is in C++11, so in theory I could use the newer range-based for loops for readability (I do in other parts of my code). Additionally, I think I could rewrite this using [`std::transform`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885095/multiply-vector-elements-by-a-scalar-value-using-stl), but I'm not sure if it would help improve the efficiency or the readability of my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the second version that you posted. Here are some problems with the first version:

**1. Prefer passing by value rather than making an explicit copy.**

This is a problem in both versions of your code. You pass `A` via constant reference. Normally this is a good thing, but then you then make a copy of `A` explicitly. In this case, it is possible to miss out on a compiler optimization called [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) ([second reference here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)). Passing by value would not cause any variable aliasing problems.

*Update*: Imagine somebody (maybe you) using your function.

```
std::vector <int> v1 = // ... insert elements
auto v2 = 3 * v1 ;
```

For simplicity, let's say variable `v2` is located at address 0x10.
When you do `3 * v1`, you are calling your function.

`R` would then be created at let's say address 0x20. When your function returns, the contents of `R` would have to be copied from 0x20 to `v2` at 0x10 and then the destructor for `R` would have to be called. Without copy elision, this would require copying every element from `R` into `v2`.

Now in C++11, there is something called [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics). This means, that without copy elision, `R` would not have to copy every element into `v2`, it could swap pointers. This is much faster, but it is still slower than copy elision.

With copy elision, instead of creating `R` at 0x20, it uses address 0x10 and builds `v2` in place. With copy elision, nothing has to be copied and no pointers have to be swapped because `v2` is built in place.

Here's how I would re-write the function:

```
template <class T, class Q>
std::vector <T> operator* (const Q c, std::vector <T> A)
{
    std::transform (A.begin (), A.end (), A.begin (),
                 std::bind1st (std::multiplies <T> () , c)) ;
    return A ;
}
```

**2. If you have to use an index-loop for some reason, rather than a range-loop or iterators, make sure you are comparing compatible types.**

You could do something like this:

```
typedef std::vector <T>::size_type size_type ;
for (size_type i = 0; i < A.size (); ++i)
```

C++11 has expanded the functionality of the `using` keyword. So instead of a `typedef`, you could also do:

```
using size_type = decltype (A.size ()) ;
```

*Update*: The reason you want to use compatible types is because overflowing a signed number is undefined behavior in C++. This means anything can happen. Consider this example:

```
const unsigned size = std::numeric_limits <int>::max () + 5 ;
std::vector <char> v1 (size) ;

for (int n = std::numeric_limits <int>::max (); n < v1.size (); ++n) {
    std::cout << n << ',' << v1.size () << '\n' ;
}
```

Different compilers on different platforms will do different things with the code above because there is undefined behavior (an `int` can never reach `std::numeric_limits <int>::max () + 5`).

**3. Consider wrapping the `std::vector` into a class.**

Programs typically use `std::vector` for many things. Overloading a global operator like you do would make me uncomfortable using your code.

**4. Obligatory [avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).**

**5. Use more meaningful variable names and typenames.**

Unless `A`, `R`, `Q`, etc are commonly understood names for special variables in your scientific community, use more meaningful names.

**6. Do not omit braces for if-statements or loops.**

This is more a subjective style guideline than anything.

Comment: These are great comments! Can I ask for clarification? 3,4,5 I get and the points are well taken. #2, is the `.size()` of something ever not an int? That may be the first time I've heard of this (and hence why I'm on code review). #1 Are you saying that there would be two copies of `A` that would be made? I'm not sure I understand copy epsilon, even after going over the links.

Comment: @Hooked 2) `.size()` almost always returns an unsigned type, usually something like `std::size_t`. An `int` cannot index every possible element of a `std::vector`. 1) I'll expand my answer with more details.

Comment: @Hooked I'm kind of busy right now, so I sort threw something together quickly. If any of it is confusing, please let me know and I'll respond hopefully within the next few days.

Comment: No, this additions are great and make sense. Thank you for providing a working example of copy-epsilon for this particular case, it helped make your point.